# Shortcut to change the pantheon-terminal font size

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I have found a link to change default terminal font size:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> is not working for me to increase font size.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to increase and decrease?

Comment: control shift and plus sign worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for **increasing**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for **decreasing** font size.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+"+" does not work for me. Ctrl+"+" works actually for me.